# ORMlite database version not incrementing after onUpgrade

Tags: android, ormlite

I've been working on an Android project and I've been using ORMLite. So far I've been able to do everything I need and I'm using a quite complex data model by now.

Now it seems I'm having problems with the onUpgrade method of the helper.

Here are the essentials of my onUpgrade method:

```
public void onUpgrade(final SQLiteDatabase db, final ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, final int newVersion) {
try {
    // Simply loop round until newest version has been reached and add the appropriate migration
    while (++oldVersion <= newVersion) {
        // Get all the available update SQL statements and execute them
        final String[] availableUpdates = SQLStaticContentHelper.getMigrationStatements(oldVersion);
        executeStatements(db, availableUpdates, true);
    }           
}
catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onUpgrade() - Can't migrate databases, bootstrap database, data will be lost", e);
    onCreate(db, connectionSource);
}
```

Here is my onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database ,ConnectionSource connectionSource) {    
try {
    //create the tables
    for (Class<?> c : allTablesArray)
    {
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, c, false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() - Not droping table " + c.getCanonicalName() + ". Does not exist.");}
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, c);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "onCreate() - Problem creating tables : ", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

The expected behavior is the following:

1. There is an upgrade
2. Do upgrade
3. if upgrade is not successful resources database
4. increment version

I actually do the upgrades and it all works fine (when it works fine). But during my tests I inserted an SQL error on purpose and it does go to onCreate and drops tables and creates tables, but it wont increment the version (next time the application is restarted it will try to upgrade again).

Anyone got an idea of why this is happening? If no exception occurs in onUpgrade the database version gets updated correctly.

Comment: Any chance you are throwing out of onCreate as well?  I would think that if the onUpgrade returns with no exception, Android OS will update the version for you.  Maybe a `RuntimeException` is being thrown?

Comment: Nop. I've even threw in a couple of log lines after the RuntimeException just to make sure. It recreates the DB and the app works as expected, but every time I restart the application it will try to upgrade again.